# How to change the location of icons in Bottom Navigation View on Android?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I want to change the location of icons in `BottomNavigation` View on Android.
You can see the relevant codes in the following:

**XML:**

```
  <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/lightBlue"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />
```

**Menu Items:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_polter"
    android:title="@string/back_polter"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_revert"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_nbe"
    android:title="@string/go_nbe"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_arrow_black"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dip"
    />
</menu>
```

As you can see in the following picture, "weiter zur Polterliste" and "weiter zur Holzerfassung" are located in the center of Bottom Navigation.
could you please tell me how I can change the location in right and left side. "weiter zur Polterliste" in the left and "weiter zur Holzerfassung" in the right side.
[image]

Comment: You can do it in java file with the help of the menu layout for the activity

Comment: can you show an image how you want

Comment: @GT I added the picture. But it is the current result. I want to change the icons in right and left side.

Comment: This might meet your need but i recommend use tablayout with custom tabview for easy handling

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use tablayout or some other layout instead of  BottomNavigationView as it supports only menu item and menu item cannot set drawables to left or right

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/red">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="ABC" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="DEF" />
    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

this meets your need also set ids seperately if any doubts comment below happy coding